# Worklight 6.1 - How to store DB data somewhere in cache to avoid multiple hits on DB on server side

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

I am using Worklight 6.1, and there are requirements that we want implement cache on the adapter level.

Whenever Worklight server starts we want to dump all the database in cache till the server restart again.

Now whenever user hit some transaction or adapter procedure which call database so instead of calling database it must read from cache.

Just help regarding this if it is there in **Worklight 6.1** version where we can implement the **cache technique**  at server end in order to avoid database hit so that we can get faster response from worklight adapter.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no "out-of-the-box" facility for this. You could create such a mechanism simply by holding data in memory - perhaps using a Java utility class you write yourself. But Worklight Adapters aren't really designed for connecting to except from the Worklight client application, so there's probably not an easy way to 'pre-fill' that cache this way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I did not understand the question, but why dont you just load the data you need into the local jsonstore at start so you can access it easily ?

Comment: It's very heavy data , so i can't use.